# Как сделать экспорт из mysql в CSV с датаой создания в имени файла?

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, crontab

Хочу сделать, программу в SQL или в crontab, чтобы экспортировала таблицу в CSV, но везде нахожу примеры только со статическим именем файла. А мне нужно чтобы к названию файла добавлялось дата и время, когда он был создан.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня в общем получилось сделать запрос, осталось разобраться как сделать автоматическую процедуру.

```
SET @time := NOW() + 0;
SET @sql := CONCAT ('SELECT `ReceivedAt`, `Message` ', 'INTO OUTFILE ', '\'c:/TEMP/export', @time, '.csv', '\' ', 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY \';\' ENCLOSED BY \'"\' FROM \`aqua_meter\` WHERE 1;');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqldump database tablename > /path/to/dump.`date '+%Y%m%d-%H:%M'`.sql
```

Если хотите именно CSV, то надо будет или написать свой однострочный перловый скрипт™, или использовать дату в имени каталога:

```
CDT=`date '+%Y%m%d-%H:%M'`
mkdir /path/to/base/dir/$CDT/ && mysqldump -T/path/to/base/dir/$CDT/ dbname table_name --fields-terminated-by=','
```

Кроме того, хороший вариант собственно CSV-дампера описан [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040816/mysqldump-in-csv-format), а как завернуть его вывод в файл с нужным именем, вы уже знаете из первой строки моего ответа.

Comment: Вообще-то ему не дамп нужен...

Comment: @Akina ага, я уж понял, но поздно. Но понял, поэтому дописал последний абзац.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @sql := CONCAT('SELECT * INTO OUTFILE \'\\\\folder_chain\\\\filenamename_prefix_', 
                   DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y-%m-%d'), 
                   '.csv\' FROM table_name;');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: У меня выдаёт ошибку, что-то здесь не так.

Comment: Не надо пересказывать своими словами. Цитируйте.